# Deploy to Azure Extension - Only Allows Creation of Github Actions Workflow. Wont Allow GitHub + Azure Pipelines Flow Creation

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I am following the steps outlined here. I am using the Deploy to Azure Extension

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/deploy-to-azure-vscode?view=azure-devops#github--azure-pipelines

I have done the following steps.

- I have managed to create a simple react app and then got the GitHub + GitHub Actions portion to work no problem.
- Now, I want to get GitHub Plus Azure Pipeline to work. So, I deleted the GitHub Actions/Workflow files, and starting over with the CICD setup.
- Next, I have enabled Use Azure Pipelines for GitHub in the extension.
- Then, as per the steps/pictures outlined in the above microsoft documentation link, I have begun the configure CICD option from the command palette.
- Selected the Visual Studio Subscription
- Selected the target web app

Now, at this point, as per the linked tutorial, it is supposed to ask me to choose a azure devops organization, so that the azure pipeline YAML file can kick in. This step never happens.

instead, VS Code will proceed to generate a GitHub Actions Workflow just as it did before.

What should I do to the GitHub to Azure Pipeline working from this extension?

**Update 1**

In case anyone is curious, I have raised a issue on the visual studio community forum. You can find that here

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1182952/github-azure-pipelines-falls-back-to-github-github.html

As of now, there is an ongoing discussion but no solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reinstalling Deploy to Azure Extension and enable Use Azure Pipelines for GitHub, and then configure CI/CD option again. If the issue persists, you can report this issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-deploy-azure/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue).

You can create a pipeline directly in your azure devops project. Check out below tutorial

[Build, test, and deploy JavaScript and Node.js apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops&tabs=code)

You will also need to create an [Azure Resource Manager service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops) to deploy to your azure resource from azure devops pipeline.

[Deploy an Azure Web App (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp-linux?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnet-core%2Cyaml)

Comment: "You can create a pipeline directly in your azure devops project" I am already able to do this. I was trying to use the visual studio code method to teach my students as they find visual studio code a little easier to use.

Comment: I have already tried the re installation but I will try on another computer. but yes, I will post an issue on github, yes.